# Typescript Compiler error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I was following JSPM getting started [guide](http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html) and I want to install jquery package so I execute below command.

`jspm install jquery`

But when I try to import it in typescript like below

`import $ from 'jquery'`

I'm getting a error from typescript compiler saying `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.` Not only for this library for other libraries I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include type definitions for `jquery` in the compilation context, you can grab them from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if that module type definition file is not available there?

Comment: Then I'd check https://github.com/typings/typings/ and if that doesn't have them then you'll have to write your own type definitions. When writing type definitions you don't have to define the entire API at once, you can just define the bits you're using. And if you just want to use a lib without type definitions you can do so with `declare module 'somelib' { var a: any; export = a; }`.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered on exactly same kind of error during VSBuild on Azure DevOps.

In my case, solution was just add new extra step `Install npm` into build pipeline and error was gone.

[image: AzureDevOps Step]

I hope it will help somebody!