# Ionic 2 build complains about cannot module lodash

Tags: cordova, angular, gulp, ionic2, typescript1.8

I am on Ionic v2, and every time I run `ionic build android` I see the following error.

> TypeScript error: /path/to/project/app/models/models.ts(1,20): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'.

There really is no side-effects that I can tell from seeing this error. For example, my mobile application runs fine in the browsers, emulators and devices. However, I'd like to know how to get rid of this error.

When I added `lodash` I had to type in the following commands.

```
npm install lodash --save
typings install lodash --save
```

`ionic info` gives me the following.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.7 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.3.1
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

Additional information on my development tool versions.

- node 4.3.1
- npm 3.8.6
- gulp CLI 1.2.1, Local 3.9.1
- cordova 6.2.0
- bower 1.7.9
- tsc 1.8.10

running `npm list --depth=0` the following are my dependencies.

```
├── @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2
├── @angular/router@2.0.0-rc.2
├── del@2.2.0
├── es6-shim@0.35.1
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── gulp-watch@4.3.5
├── ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.8
├── ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript@1.1.0
├── ionic-gulp-fonts-copy@1.0.0
├── ionic-gulp-html-copy@1.0.0
├── ionic-gulp-sass-build@1.0.0
├── ionic-gulp-scripts-copy@2.0.0
├── ionic-native@1.2.4
├── ionicons@3.0.0
├── lodash@4.13.1
├── reflect-metadata@0.1.3
├── run-sequence@1.1.5
├── rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
└── zone.js@0.6.12
```

Comment: +1 I have noticed the same issue. Also happens with `jquery`: `TypeScript error: Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.`

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102441/typescript-compiler-error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-jquery). For whatever reason, the compiler complains because it cannot find the type definitions for `lodash` (and in my case `jquery`).

To solve it, I just added a triple-slash reference to my typings as the very first line of my `app.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

And all of the errors went away.

Comment: I had to modify `typings/main.d.ts` to add the reference.

Comment: Part of the problem was that I was on an older version of `typings` which was generating code in `main.d.ts`. I then upgraded my `typings`and now the references are placed in `index.d.ts`.